# Создать временный файл, отдать пользователю, и удалить

Tags: файлы, php

Можно как то это организовать по простому ?

Вот я создаю файл:

```
if(isset($_GET['save'])){

    $data = null;
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['uri']) ? $_SESSION['uri']."\r\n" : '';
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['key']) ? $_SESSION['key']."\r\n" : '';
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['pass1']) ? $_SESSION['pass1']."\r\n" : '';
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['pass2']) ? $_SESSION['pass2']."\r\n" : '';
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['pass3']) ? $_SESSION['pass3']."\r\n" : '';
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['pass4']) ? $_SESSION['pass4']."\r\n" : '';
    $data .= isset($_SESSION['pass5']) ? $_SESSION['pass5']."\r\n" : '';

    $filename = './datasave/'.$_SESSION['key'].'.txt';
    $fileurl = 'http://'.HOST.'/datasave/'.$_SESSION['key'].'.txt';
    file_put_contents($filename, $data);
    header('Location: '.$fileurl);
    exit;

}
```

Отдаю его юзеру, и мне нужно его удалить, после того как юзер его получил.

Что можно сделать ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще существует специальная функнция tmpfile();
Но здесь я как понимаю нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь смог скачать что-то.
Для таких целей применяется передача хидеров Content-type и Content-Disposition: attachment

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.txt"');
print "ЭТОТ ТЕКСТ БУДЕТ СОХРАНЕН";
```

Comment: Ну можно и так. Благодарю